# c: how to correctly print values from a BMP file as int in another file

Tags: c

SYSTEM INFO:

> ravi@ubuntu:~/Desktop/File$ uname -a Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-29-generic
>    #42~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 14 15:31:16 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

I am trying to copy first 2000 values of a BMP file (im.bmp) in decimal format in another file (new.txt).  But by the following code I am getting only values in characters written in my text file:

> BMfK^@^@^@^@^@^@6^D^@^@(^@^@^@�^@^@^@�^@^@^@^A^@^H^@^@^@^@^@0G^@^@�^N^@^@�^N^@^@$

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
FILE *fp,*fw;
int i;
unsigned char buffer[10000];
fp=fopen("im.bmp","rb");
fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
fread(buffer,2000,4,fp);
for(i=0;i<2000;i++)
{
printf("%d\n",buffer[i]);
}

fw=fopen("new.txt","w+");
if(fw==NULL)

{

printf("Error opening file\n");
}


int byteswritten;
byteswritten=fwrite(&buffer[0],sizeof(int),2000,fw);
    printf("%d\n",byteswritten);


fclose(fw);
fclose(fp);

return(0);
}
```

now using fprintf() but still gettinf the same result

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
FILE *fp,*fw;
int i;
unsigned char buffer[10000];
fp=fopen("im.bmp","rb");
fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
fread(buffer,2000,4,fp);
for(i=0;i<2000;i++)
{
printf("%d\n",buffer[i]);
}

fw=fopen("new.txt","w+");
if(fw==NULL)

{

printf("Error opening file\n");
}


int byteswritten;
//byteswritten=fwrite(&buffer[0],sizeof(int),2000,fw);
byteswritten=fprintf(fw,buffer,"%d");
printf("%d\n",byteswritten);


fclose(fw);
fclose(fp);

return(0);
}
```

So how to print the values as int e.g. 42 will be printed as 66, (and not B as here), 4d wil be printed as 77, (not M as here) and similar action for next values

Comment: Have you tried casting the unsigned char to an int?

Answer (score 0):

Just as `fread()` reads binary values, `fwrite()` writes binary values. You need to use `fprintf()` to print formatted text values.

Comment: I have used fprintf() here is my code
    #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
FILE *fp,*fw;
int i;
unsigned char buffer[10000];
fp=fopen("im.bmp","rb");
fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
fread(buffer,2000,4,fp);
for(i=0;i<2000;i++)
{
printf("%d\n",buffer[i]);
}

fw=fopen("new.txt","w+");
if(fw==NULL)

{

printf("Error opening file\n");
}


int byteswritten;
//byteswritten=fwrite(&buffer[0],sizeof(int),2000,fw);
byteswritten=fprintf(fw,buffer,"%d");
printf("%d\n",byteswritten);


fclose(fw);
fclose(fp);

return(0);
}

Comment: You are missing the point. `fprintf()` prints `formatted text` (you know `'0' = 0 + 48`). So using `fprintf()`, you are writing `ASCII` codes into your second file instead of the numerical values. `fwrite()` causes no such conversion.

Comment: @David C. Rankin can you please highlight where I am printing ASCII values in my code. I have used "%d" in my second code for printing decimal values.

Comment: `fprintf(fw,buffer,"%d");` You have `fwite` commented out above. Why?

Comment: because in second code i wanted to use 'fprintf();' only. See my first code i have used 'fwrite()'

Comment: @RaviSharma: You have switched the arguments to `fprintf()`; also, you can't print an entire buffer at a time unless you actually want to interpret the buffer as a string. See Weather Vane's answer.

Answer (score 0):

OP says he wants 42 as 66 which means he wants the decimal ASCII values

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp, *fw;
    int i, bytesread;
    unsigned char buffer[10000];

    fp = fopen("im.bmp","rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening input file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    bytesread = fread(buffer, 1, 2000, fp);   //  swapped 2nd and 3rd arg

    /* for(i=0; i<bytesread; i++)
        printf("%d,", buffer[i]); */

    fw = fopen("new.txt","wt+");
    if (fw==NULL) {
        printf("Error opening output file\n");
        fclose (fp);
        return 1;
    }

    for(i=0; i<bytesread; i++)
        fprintf(fw, "%d,", buffer[i]);
    printf("\nRead %d bytes\n", bytesread);

    fclose(fw);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
```

}